# Django South Migration introspect_test

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I'm trying to do a simple migrate and I'm getting the error

`django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1050, "Table 'introspect_test' already exists")`.

When looking at the actual `MySQL` database, I see no table called `introspect_test` nor do I have such a table defined in any Django model. A little bit of Google-Fu tells me that this `introspect_test` has something to do with foreign key constraints and South's error checking... or something.

I think this whole problem originated form my own error - while in the middle of executing a `python manage.py migrate app_name` I accidently hit `CTRL-C` and, thus, stopped the process.

I guess the question is: how do I get rid of this mysterious `introspect_test` so that I can migrate normally?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, silly me... what I didn't realise is that the table `introspect_test` is alls caps and, thus, isn't sorted alphabetically. It turns out that, due to a small laptop screen, doing `show tables;` listed all the tables but cut off the top few. Since the table in question is labelled as `INTROSPECT_TEST` it is at the top.

I did a quick `drop table INTROSPECT_TEST` and then migrated normally.

Fixed.